# Having an anchor tag within an HTML button tag

Tags: html, css, button, anchor, href

I have an anchor tag  within a button tag description in HTML as below:

```
<button type="submit" onClick="handleSubmit()">Desc.... 
   <a href="https://......." target="_blank">Click here for more details</a>
</button>
```

Now when I click on the anchor text, the action "handleSubmit()" executes instead of going to my https:// link.So apparently, my  text is also being treated as a button instead of a hyperlink.

I tried adding the z-index property to my CSS for (z-index: 1) in order to make it independently clickable so it overlays on top of the button tag, but no joy!

But if I right-click on the  text, I do see the option of opening the https link in a new tab and it does so perfectly. Only when I click on it normally(left click), the button click handler executes as if its the button being clicked instead of the anchor tag.

How can I fix this? Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: If you never want your button to submit, a better approach would probably be to only use an anchor and no button, then style it like your button styles.

Comment: I do want the button to submit though. I want the button to do something if the user clicks submit. The anchor tag is just a hyperlink, that should display additional information when clicked.

Comment: Do you want the button to submit AND to display more details if the anchor is clicked?

Comment: your button should not have a link inside. This will only mess things up, use event listeners for your button to handle the click.

Comment: When the user clicks the anchor tag, I want him to be taken to a new https link -button 'submit' should not be clicked in this case. And when the user clicks on anywhere other than the anchor tag, the submit button should execute.

Comment: I second what @rafaelcastrocouto is saying, just don't put the link inside of the button. It's not needed there and doesn't make much sense. If you really have to have it there then use event.preventDefault() to suppress the link behaviour.

Comment: Agreed with the other two. If the button should work AND the anchor should work, AND the behaviour for clicking each of them is different, then you are much better off (from an ease of programming perspective, as well as from a UX design perspective) to just have the anchor not be inside the button, but after / before it instead.

Comment: Just wanted to add a scenario that lead me to this question.  I am trying to overlay a dismiss [x] on top of a button.  In my particular case, the buttons are created dynamically based on user input.  I am looking for a simple/intuitive way for the user to get rid of the button when it is no longer desired.   I had embedded an anchor tag within a div that I then used absolute positioning to put in the upper right corner of the button.  Unfortunately, clicking on the link activates the button.  (And, I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require javascript.)

Answer (score -1):

I don't quite understand if you intend to use the function inside the *onClick* in any situation. 
You can swap the wrapping of elements so that the button is inside the link; also you could move the link inside the onClick like this:

```
onClick="window.location.href='link'"
```

Thought these can be a couple solutions, you need to clarify the exact behaviour you expect to obtain from your code.